# invoking user_name variable outside function and class

Tags: python

I want to access the user_name variable outside function and class also how to do this?

Here is my Code

```
def DocumentCreateView(request):
    user_name = request.user.email

    print(user_name)
    int_rep = int(rep_no)
    flag = 1
    count = 0
    i = 1
    j = 0
```

This is code where i want to access user_name outside class and function

```
path_to_piepline1 = "lazy-test/users/"+**user_name**+"/input"
print("--- first argument ---", path_to_piepline1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should *return* it:

```
def DocumentCreateView(request):

    user_name = request.user.email

    print(user_name)
    int_rep = int(rep_no)
    flag = 1
    count = 0
    i = 1
    j = 0

    return user_name
```

And then call this function:

```
user_name = DocumentCreateView(<pass your argument here>)
path_to_piepline1 = "lazy-test/users/"+ user_name +"/input"
```

If, however, you don't return it in any form (on its own or alongside other data), and it remains local, there will be no way to access it after the function returns.

Comment: what is something ?

Comment: `DocumentCreateView` takes one argument, but your question doesn't specify how you're using it, so I used a dummy variable name

Comment: from session function code takes some username and that username will pass to path_to_pipeline1

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're saying. How are you calling the function `DocumentCreateView`? You must be passing some argument to it, otherwise it would error out.

Comment: the argument which are you saying is dynamic always...can i put "user_name" in DocumentCreateView(""Here"") ??

Comment: I don't think so: `user_name` is what this function _returns_. There is no such variable before you call the function

Comment: simply just what i want is the value of username outside class

Comment: @swapnildeshpande, you should show how you're calling your function and what the class looks like. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of the class and use it to call the function and return the value of username.